# How to Scaffold DbContext but ignore tables in database

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

How can I use Scaffold DbContext without including tables? Our database has a lot of tables which I don't need - I only need to call a couple of stored procedures.

I'm using a .NET Core console application with *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServe*r, *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools* and *Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design* as my packages.

I tried to check [Entity Framework Core tools reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/dotnet#dotnet-ef-dbcontext-scaffold) but you have to reference at least one table using -t/--table

Comment: *I only need to call a couple of stored procedures* -- Then you don't need a `DbContext` either. Use a tool like Dapper.

Comment: @GertArnold yes, i can do that but is there a way using ef core? and on how i can use it?

Comment: Just take a `DbContext`. It's not that you can only use it when it's _scaffolded_.

Comment: Yup, all did a `Scaffold DbContext` then get only one table, after that i just deleted it in the Models folder to make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

If the table is not to complex or it is not updated often, then just skip Scaffold and build the DBContext and Table class manually, don't forget to decorate with key if needed.

An alternative to this is using [EF Core Powertools](https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools).